# how to install python error free in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm new to ubuntu 16.04. somehow I uninstalled my built-in python and again I tried to install using

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7
```

but this is the error i got

> Reading package lists... Done
>       Building dependency tree
>       Reading state information... Done
>       python2.7 is already the newest version (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.2).
>       You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
>       The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>       alacarte : Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
>       inkscape : Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>       python-bs4 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
>                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>       python-chardet : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
>                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>       python-gi : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not going to be installed
>                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>        python-html5lib : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
>                      Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>       python-lxml : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
>                  Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
>       python-numpy : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not going to be installed
>                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>         python-pil : Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
>                 Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not going to be installed
>                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>        python-pil.imagetk : Depends: python-tk (>= 2.7.7-2) but it is not going          to be installed
>                         Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be      installed
>                         Depends: python (>= 2.7~) but it is not going to be installed
>                         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>         python-pkg-resources : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
>                           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>         python-six : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
>                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
>        E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or     specify a solution).

I don't know what any of these mean? I couldn't even locate my python version
do I have to be worried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please learn how to ask great questions first. This is highly opinionated and not concise at all. Please re-word your question.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with python installed. Look at the first line of the error

> Reading state information... Done python2.7 is already the newest version (2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.2).

Try command `python -V` to find out the installed version of python in the system

Comment: I had some software which depended on python dependencies. but they got uninstalled or they are not running. error are something like this:

Comment: Have tried doing `sudo apt-get -f  install python2.7`